# Поключить бд к php проекту

Tags: php, sql-server

На Openserver есть курсовой проект на php, препод запретил использовать PhpMyAdmin(упустим подробносни почему так)
У меня вопрос, а как еще можна подключить бд
Пролистал много страниц в гугле, ничего толкового не нашел.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin не имеет никакого отношения к подключению бд, это просто веб-интерфейс для управления mysql. Непонятно кого куда нужно подключить и в чём конкретная проблема у вас

Comment: @andreymal особенно с учетом того что в тэгах sql-server

Comment: вам не страницы в гугле надо читать, а документацию к пхп в разделе работы с БД.

Answer (score 0):

К БД можно подключится с помощью

- бесплатной программы HeidiSQL
  ([скачать](https://www.heidisql.com)).

- командной строки: `mysql -u username -p`, где username - имя пользователя. Нажмите кнопку Enter. Затем введите введите свой пароль. При успешной авторизации, появляется приглашение `mysql>`. Чтобы отобразить список баз данных, введите: `show databases;`